# Rails3: unable to install forgot_password plugin in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, generator, restful-authentication, forgot-password

I am using restful_authentication plugin in my Rails3 app and now in trying to install forgot_password plugin to work with it, there was no problem installing the plugin that all went pretty smooth but i can't seem to generate forgot_password.

I was told to run the following command after I install the forgot_password plugin:

```
ruby script/generate forgot_password password user
```

but since im using Rails3 i ran the above command like this:

```
rails generate forgot_password password user
```

but it always quits with the error:

```
                Could not find generator forgot_password.
```

oh and one more thing, the actual command looks like this:

```
ruby script/generate forgot_password <password-model-name> <user-model-name>
```

Can anyone tell me what that **password-model-name** is for, i mean i only have a model for user i don't have one for password then what am i suppose to do,

thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure, it looks like it may be a Rails 2 plugin you are trying to run on a Rails 3 app.  I would check the vendor/plugin directory to see if you can find any generators and if you can copy and paste them to lib/generators/ or lib/rails_generators/, as that is where Rails 3 may look as I have come to read.  If they don't exists there is your problem.  Not to mention last time I checked Rails 3 uses the command:

> rails generate

and not

> ruby script/generate

With the same syntax after this part.